# create email address validation in this format in javascript

Tags: javascript

**An acceptable email address should meet following criteria to be called a valid email address**

> Contains exactly one '@'
>   Minimum 2 characters before '@'
>   Any characters including numbers and special characters before '@' are allowed.
>   Contains at least one '.' after '@'
>   Any number of '.' are allowed after '@'
>   Only alphabets and '.' are allowed after '@'
>   Minimum 2 characters required between '@' and '.' after '@'
>   Minimum 2 characters required between two '.' if more than one '.' is present after '@'
>   Minimum 2 characters required after last '.'

---

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server" CssClass="stText" MaxLength="100" onblur="fnEmail(this)" placeholder="Email" TabIndex="7"></asp:TextBox>
                        <br />
<asp:Label ID="lblErrorTxtEmail" runat="server" CssClass="stlblError" Text=""></asp:Label>
```

---

```
function fnEmail() {
```

`var objEmail = document.getElementById("txtEmail");

var objErrorLabel = document.getElementById("lblErrorTxtEmail");


var EmailPat = /^(\".*\"|[A-Za-z0-9.-_]\w*){2,}@(\[\d{2,3}(\.\d{2,3}){3}]|[A-Za-z]{2,}\w*(\.[A-Za-z]\w*)+)$/;

var objMatchArray = objEmail.value.match(EmailPat);

if (objMatchArray === null) {

    objErrorLabel.innerHTML = "Invalid Email Address";  //strErrorInvalidEmailAddress;
    objEmail.className = "TextBoxWithError"
    return false;
}
else {
    var arrStrEmail = objEmail.value.substring(objEmail.value.lastIndexOf("@") + 1, objEmail.value.length).split(".");

    for (var i = 0; i < arrStrEmail.length; i++) {
        if (arrStrEmail[i].length < 2) {
            objErrorLabel.innerHTML = "Invalid Email Address";  
            objEmail.className = "TextBoxWithError"
    return false;
        }
        else {
            objErrorLabel.innerHTML = "";
            objEmail.className = "TextBox";
        }
    }
}`

}

Comment: SO is not a coding service. Shows us your attempt.

Comment: I use this Regular expration string but it not work
<br/>
   var EmailPat = /^(([\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9_]){2,}@([\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]){2,}\.[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\.]*[a-zA-Z]{2,})*$/;
<br/>
in this query Every "." I use two character

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution

```
var filter1 = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
            if (!filter1.test(email)) {
            alert("Email id is not valid");
            }
```

Comment: I have create Every "." use Two character

like >> aa@aa.aa.aa.aa.aa   >> valide

aa@aa.aa.a.aa.aa >> not valide

Comment: `Contains at least one '.' after '@'` and `Any number of '.' are allowed after '@' ` this is your requirement :)

Comment: yes but after . contain minimum two character like this ".co"

Comment: It is checking for every dot

Comment: Ya every dot check it